# Installing System dynamic (Powersim studio 5) in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, installation, wine

Is there any  way to install **Powersim Studio 5** to 12.04?

I had this software work on my previous Windows XP, nevertheless, after my migration to Ubuntu until now, I still cannot use this software.

I've tried to installing it on 12.04 using **Wine**, but it didn't worked.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

One option is using a virtual machine (VM), you can use oracle's [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) or vmware's [VMware Player](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/overview.html) to create one, then you can install back XP in the VM (hopefully you still have your licence) finally you can install **Powersim Studio 5** on XP as usual.

More on virtual machines [Virtual Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine).